# Issue with serving different app from subfolder of wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, apache, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site running at the root of my domain. e.g `http://www.example.com` as I needed site to run www url I had changed the siteurl in wp-options table to http://www.example.com now when I try to visit non www url it redirects me to www variation. this is all working fine

But now I have created a subfolder 'app' there which serves an angular app. Now when I visit `http://example.com/app/` then it works.. but when I visit `http://www.example.com/app/` it shows me wordpress 404 page. is it not possible to have this setup?

Server is aws + apache.

Comment: Is the `aap` the subdirectory have `.htaccess` file ? if yes then what is in the file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using an .htaccess file you can add this before the rewrite rule for wordpress index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

It checks if the requests start with app/ and pass it without modification.

Comment: Although still have no idea why it was not working in first place.. adding these lines do solves the issues. So will accept the answer.

Comment: If you post the complete htaccess file we can see where is the issue.

Comment: <code><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/appointment/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
</code>
if works fine

but [domain name]/appointment/booking  this url

give me 404

Answer (score 0):

Please check angular app where to serve, means which port on run and also check your main wordpress site where?